# Invalid authentication tag length (aes-256-gcm)

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I am encountering some issues when trying to decrypt a file stored in my NodeJS server. Currently, this is my method to encrypt a file:

```
function encryptAndMoveFile(sourcePath, destinationPath) {
  try {
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(12);
    const cipher = createCipher(iv);

    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(sourcePath);
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(destinationPath);

    writeStream.write(iv);

    readStream.pipe(cipher).pipe(writeStream);

    cipher.on('end', () => {
      const authTag = cipher.getAuthTag();
      fs.appendFileSync(destinationPath, authTag);
      fs.unlinkSync(sourcePath);
    });

    cipher.on('error', (error) => {
      console.log('Error during encryption:', error);
      writeStream.end();
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error in encryption and moving file: ", error);
  }
}

function createCipher(initializationVector) {
  const keyBuffer = Buffer.from(ENCRYPTION_KEY, 'hex');
  return crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', keyBuffer, initializationVector); 
}
```

And for the decryption, I have this function that takes the encrypted data of the file as a parameter, and returns the decrypted data:

```
function decryptFile(encryptedData) {
  try {
    const keyBuffer = Buffer.from(ENCRYPTION_KEY, 'hex');
    const iv = encryptedData.slice(0, 12);
    const authTag = encryptedData.slice(encryptedData.length - 16);
    const dataToDecrypt = encryptedData.slice(12, encryptedData.length - 16);

    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', keyBuffer, iv);

    decipher.setAuthTag(authTag);

    let decryptedData = decipher.update(dataToDecrypt, 'binary', 'utf8');
    decryptedData += decipher.final('utf8');

    return decryptedData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error during decryption', error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

However, it always throws the following error: `Invalid authentication tag length: 31'`. This happens although I check the length of `authTag`, and it always gives me a 16, which is the length in bytes of the authentication tag in aes-256-gcm. So, what am I doing wrong in here?

A consideration to note, my ENCRYPTION_KEY is the same for both the encryption and decryption processes, so I don't think that's the problem here.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Maybe you load the ciphertext incorrectly (you post only the decryption function). Post non-productive sample data: key and content of the file with the encrypted data (e.g. hex encoded).